# How do I get make to just compile?

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I want to just compile using `make` and not link. Within my directory I have the following: Makefile, pi*, pi.cpp, pi.o

In the Makefile this is the code:

```
pi: pi.o
 c++ -O0 pi.o -o pi

pi.o: pi.cpp
 c++ -O0 pi.cpp -c
```

How do I get `make` to just compile:

> c++ -O0 pi.cpp -c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean running only part for getting object file? Try runing `make pi.o`

Comment: Okay so basically I was going to comment earlier that it doesn't work and only shows that "make: 'pi.o' is up to date" but then I realized that I would need to rm pi.o from the directory and then I tried what you said and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Harsh1010 you can add this step to makefile as well. Like first step to clean your output (let say it will be called `clean`), another (`pi.o`) will depend on this `clean`, meaning that you will have line like that: `pi.o: pi.cpp clean`